# How do I get rid of backslashes and double quotes in php json string

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to get rid of the double quotes and backslashes from my JSON code but nothing seems to work. Obviously I am doing something wrong here. Would somebody be so kind to point me in the right direction:

Here is a portion of my PHP code that has the HTML to be returned. As you can see I tried escaping then sending it, and removing the backslashes before sending it via json_encode(). Tried them individually and all together. Am I double encoding or what?  Thanks in advance.

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        $response = "";
        foreach($returnSmt as $row){

            $response .= '<div class=\"col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2\">              
                <div class=\"panel panel-default panelFullLink\">
                    <a href=\"topic.php?id='.$row['topic_id'].'\" class="fullClickLink\"></div></div>';
        }

        //Here is the code that I tried in a few ways to get rid of the slashes and double quotes
        $response = preg_replace("@[\\r|\\n|\\t]+@", "", $response);
        $response = stripslashes($response);
        $response = trim($response);
        echo str_replace('\/','/', json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
}
```

If needed, here is my AJAX function that handles the JSON code.

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "sortResults.php",
        data:  {
            infiniteScrollData: 1,
            start: start,
            limit: limit
            },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            if(response == "reachedMax")
                reachedMax = true;
                else{
                    start += limit;
                    $("#rowDisplayResults").append(response);
                }

        }
    });
```

Comment: You are using backslashes to try and escape the double quotes, however, your string is encased in single quotes. So your back slashes are not needed in `$response`.

Comment: Also, after looking at your ajax, it looks like you are just appending HTML (the entire response), so, I don't think you need to worry about back slashes at all.

Comment: The issue is that when displayed it inserts backslashes. <a href="\&quot;topic.php?id=19\&quot;" class="\&quot;fullClickLink\&quot;">. I had removed all of the backslashes from the code and still it inserts them when displayed.

Comment: Yes, because you are inserting them. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging form your AJAX and your PHP, it looks like you are simply appending the entire response's HTML to the document somewhere. So really, you don't need to worry about backslashes at all.

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    $response = '';
    foreach($returnSmt as $row){

        $response .= '<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">              
            <div class="panel panel-default panelFullLink">
                <a href="topic.php?id='.$row['topic_id'].'" class="fullClickLink"></div></div>';
    }

    // No need to JSON encode it, just echo your HTML:
    echo $response;
}
```

Then, your AJAX stays as you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the backslashes as they are useless since you are quoting your string with simple quotes.
Aslo, consider using the [addslashes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function to easily escape string that will be interpreted later.

Comment: This has already been posted as a comment, which is what this should have been too.

Comment: Woops, comment wasn't here when I writed. Also, the comment is now moved to an answer so...